# sort by sum of column and alphabetically if null or zero

Tags: sql, hana

I have a requirement to get sum of INVQTY column in ascending order by the sum of INVQTY, which my query accomplishes. But in some cases sum of INVQTY is 0 or null, in that case I need the CUSTOMER column to come in ascending order but alphabetically.

How do I accomplish this ?

I am using HANA database.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER AS CUSTOMER,
SUM(INVQTY) AS INVQTY
FROM TEST_TABLE
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
ORDER BY INVQTY
```

Data example:

```
CUSTOMER   INVQTY
A          0
B          10
B          20
C          0
```

Current result:

```
CUSTOMER   INVQTY
C          0
A          0
B          30
```

Expected result:

```
CUSTOMER   INVQTY
A          0
C          0
B          30
```

Comment: There seemed to be a big error in question -> corrected. Example added. Please edit your question if what I assumed is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two columns in the `ORDER BY` as follows:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER AS CUSTOMER,
SUM(INVQTY) AS INVQTY
FROM TEST_TABLE
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
ORDER BY INVQTY, CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked. I didn't know adding customer there would sort alphabetically by default.

Comment: I have a follow up question on this. If 2 customer values have same sum(INVQTY) values, then also I need "customer" to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: Yes, that will also be taken care @Nadeem

Comment: I see,thats right. I wasn't checking it properly. Thanks again